# Biholomorphic map between the upper half plane and a portion of the unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $\mathbb{H} = \{z\in \mathbb{C}| \ Im(z) > 0 \}$.

I want to find a biholomorphic map between $\mathbb{H}$ and $D(0,1) \cap \{$first quadrant$\}$.

Any hint ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decompose it into simpler steps.

You know how to conformally map a half plane to a disk. That should make it easy to find a conformal map between a quadrant (a half half-plane) and a half-disk.

Finding conformal maps between a half-plane and a quadrant, respectively a half-disk and a quarter-disk should be easy too. Then you compose

Half-plane $\to $ quadrant $\to$ half-disk $\to$ quarter-disk.